# DocuSign API - Set the "Sender Name" and "Sender Email" of the Envelope/Email Notification

Tags: docusignapi

I'm successfully using the OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow to authenticate with DocuSign and send envelopes. When the email notification is received by the signer recipient there are a number of references to the name/email address of the DocuSign Account, e.g. the sender appears as:

```
Fred Smith via DocuSign <dse_demo@docusign.net>
```

And in the body of the email it includes `Fred Smith` and their email address `fred@acme.com`. We would like to be able to dynamically/programatically change these references in the email notifications that are sent when we create the envelope.

I haven't seen any options for this in the API docs so far - is this is possible using the Authorization Code Grant flow?

Comment: You cannot change the sender information (as far as I'm aware). Some aspects of the email body however can be overridden. In the EnvelopeDefinition you can define the EmailSubject, EmailBlurb and EmailSettings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anu6is (see comment) is correct. The `sender` of the DocuSign envelope will be shown as the sender in the email notification (if used).

If your DocuSign account has multiple registered users, then your application can change the sender by either:

- having the different sender authenticate with the application (OAuth Authorize Code or Implicit grants)
- using the JWT grant to programmatically impersonate the different account users and to send on their behalf